# Can we translate the description of Epiphany back to English?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2016

The hat, ["Epiphany"](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/epiphany), currently has a description in a language other than English (not Italian):

> La Befana vien di notte con le scarpe tutte rotte

I can't read that and a lot of other users will not be able to read that. Sure, we could read the short summary which says, "post or vote on January 6th" but for consistency and for the people who can't read that, can we translate the description back to English? Or at the very least, add an English translation since it's a reference to an [Italian children's song](http://www.mamalisa.com/?t=es&p=3102) (thank you, @Glorfindel for that)?

By the way, if you translate that on Google with the setting on "Detect Language", it thinks that it is in Italian and this is what it means:

> La Befana comes by night with broken shoes all

Comment: It's an [Italian children's song](http://www.mamalisa.com/?t=es&p=3102).

Comment: More importantly, if it's for "_post or vote on January 6th_", why have I got one on the 5th (UK time)?

Comment: One of the things I strive to do when helping people on the SE network is to foster the thought that you can research problems rather than just be told the answer. I know a lot of users come here asking to be spoonfed, but I think for a fun event like winter bash, they can figure out how to figure it out.

Comment: @TripeHound You got it because *somewhere* in the world it is the 6th. SE doesn't (*ahem*) know where you are, so it gives it 5th to 7th January :)

Comment: My problem isn't that it's not in English, but that it doesn't do its job of explaining what the hat was awarded for.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The purpose of the hat, and of the writing is to entice you to google it and [discover the Italian tradition of the Befana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befana) - the poem is in Italian and there's no unequivocal English translation to look up.

[image: Befana]

Of course, I understand this is an English site, but remember that non-English-speakers don't get everything translated in their own language the rest of the year, they have to look up stuff constantly, and they accept that gracefully.

I am sure we can tolerate a tiny Easter (Christmas?) Egg in an optional hat game running for three weeks, on an exceptional basis?

Comment: Of course! I'm just used to all the descriptions (for like most things) to be English. There are lots of other question related to translating something back to English so I though this was valid as well. Oops!

Comment: Arrived here after googling it 8-|

Comment: but for what achievement this hat is rewarded?

Comment: È arrivata la Befana!!

Comment: Yes, I was enticed to go straight to Google. The problem is that I went to Google Translate, not Google Search, so I was left just as confused as I started. Thanks for the explanation.